# Issue using postgres jdbc in jenkins shared library

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is a new class in a shared library for Jenkins.

The shared library is loaded via the standard method under Manage Jenkins > Configure System

```
@Grab('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0')
import org.postgresql.Driver
import groovy.sql.Sql

class postgresClass implements Serializable {
    def dbconnection
    def dbURL
    def dbUsername
    def dbPassword
    def dbDriver

    postgresClass(databaseConfig) {
        //Set any instance variables required.    
        this.dbURL = databaseConfig.sql.url
        this.dbUsername = databaseConfig.sql.username
        this.dbPassword = databaseConfig.sql.password
        this.dbDriver = databaseConfig.sql.driver
    }

    def getConnection() {
        return Sql.newInstance(dbURL,dbUsername,dbPassword,dbDriver)
    }
}
```

The databaseConfig object is configured as:

```
def databaseConfig = [
    url: 'jdbc:postgresql://myhost:1433;databaseName=mydatabase',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    driver: 'org.postgresql.Driverr'
]
```

When MyClass.getConnection() is called it fails with:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://myhost:1433;databaseName=mydatabase
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Not sure why the '@Grab' and 'import' are not making the driver available.

I have tried adding:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
```

as suggest elsewhere but this cause the class to fail compilation - Jenkins starts to see it as a script rather than a class and so throws the duplicate class name error.

I also tried adding:
 `ServiceLoader<Driver> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Driver.class);`
and
 `DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver())`
but neither worked for me
I need to use a jdbc driver and a java or groovy library to connect and query sql, as this shared lib needs to run on different jenkins servers where I cannot control the infrastructure, install plugins, or even do psql shell commands or install it.

Comment: I faced with something similar while working with SQLITE3, I didn't find a solution but I decided to use the CLI tool `sqlite3` via `sh` e.g: `sqlite3 -cmd ".timeout ${this.acquireLockTimeout}" ${args.join(' ')} $sqlPath "$query"`